# PHP regex - what am I doing wrong now in this case?

Tags: php, regex

using the regular expression:

```
$pattern = "/adminvalues = \"\([^']+, '[^']+', MD5\('[^']+'\), '[^']+','[^']+','[^']+',[^']+,[^']+\)\";/";
preg_match($pattern, $data, $results);
print_r($results);
```

searching the following text (values within brackets can change... hence the need for regex...):

```
adminvalues = "(NULL, 'Admin12345', 'MD5(Admin12345)', 'Admin12345', 'Admin12345', 5, 0, 0)";
```

so am looking for a pattern (in reg-ex) that matches essentially the following (I think...):

```
[adminvalues = "(] [any character] [, '] [any character] [', MD5('] [any character] ['), '] [any character] [', '] [any character]  [', ] [any character] [, ] [any character] [, ] [any character] [)";]
```

Where: **Any character is one or more of any combination of (letter / number / symbol)**

I get no matches using the PHP code at the top - so I've obviously done something wrong! I just can't spot the error myself. (I only started using regex this morning really...) What have I done wrong? :)

**Solve:** (Thanks to Amal Murali)
Using htmlspecialchars() when reading the php script being used as `$data` (rather than just to display contents)

Comment: Searching, but searching for *what* exactly? What are you trying to extract? Every value in the "array"?

Comment: Simple: start cutting back on the regex, and until it starts matching things, then start adding the cut bits back in. when it stops matching, you've gotten to where the problem is. For a fairly 'regular' string like, you might be better off with some simple regexes to extract the entire `()` section, then treat it as a CSV string and explode() it instead.

Comment: I quoted "array" for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
$pattern = <<<PATTERN
~
  adminvalues\s*=\s*
  "
  \(                  
    [^,]+,\s*
    '[^']+',\s*
    MD5\('[^']+'\),\s*
    '[^']+',\s*
    '[^']+',\s*
    \d,\s*
    \d,\s*
    \d\s*
  \)
  ";
~xm
PATTERN;
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/oX4zX5)

Comment: Could it possibly be a multi-line file/string? If so possibly use the m or s switch. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php